# Logback: Log file can't be created when on work profile

Tags: android, logback

We discovered an issue recently where a user who has their device setup on a work profile had ran into an issue that stopped our log file being created. We try to write our log file to the Data directory as below:

```
<fileNamePattern>${DATA_DIR}/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

The problem is that this directory doesn't exist on the work profile. I'm wondering did anyone else come across this issue and can anyone offer a solution that doesn't require extra permission requirements but works across both work & non-work android users ?

Cheers

Comment: DATA_DIR = "C:\\Windows\\Data"; Indeed, that dir does not exist.

Comment: `${DATA_DIR}` is not a common notation to access the app-private data directory in a Java based Android app. It seems like you are using a third party framework for building your app and this framework seems to be non-aware of work profiles.

Comment: @Robert Apologies this is using the Logback library, I had tagged it with that but it wasn't obvious from my question at all. I have edited the title to include Logback

Comment: Are you using plain logback or this modified version [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android)?

Comment: @Robert I am using the modified version you linked. On the "Raise issue" for questions they ask we post our questions here with the tags on the issue